# How to run exported python package from within?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

I took a few days to understand `pip install` workflow, and now that I'm aware of at list main problems, I'm facing this `import` issue that I just can't find a workaround.

I have this minimum executable example:

```py
packagetest/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    aux.py
setup.py
```

aux.py

```py
class Aux:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

main.py

```py
from packagetest.aux import Aux

def printAux():
    print(Aux('aux1'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    printAux()
```

setup.py

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='packagetest',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

That's it. That's my python package.
Then I run `pip install .` and in another project, let's say `project2.py`, I can call:

```py
from packagetest import main

main.printAux()
```

and that's my output:

```py
aux1
```

Everything works perfectly, except not. If I run `pip uninstall packagetest`, go into my `packagetest/` folder and then try to run `python main.py` I catch this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from packagetest.aux import Aux
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packagetest'
```

That's because my `packagetest` is not installed and  python can't find `packagetest` when i'm importing it with `from packagetest.aux import Aux`. if I change it to `from aux import Aux` it works perfectly, but in this case I can't export this project using `pip install` because `aux` will not be recognized as a module. I tried and I catch this another error on `project2.py`:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from packagetest import main
  File "/home/leonardo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/packagetest/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from aux import Aux
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aux'
```

My question is how to make my project executable without installing it? **I want an import that works in both cases**, and don't want my modules to be executable only it my package is installed inside pip packages. I wan't to clone my repo and execute my project in a new machine without being forced to install in via pip.

Is it possible? How big projects handle that?

Comment: Big projects *don't* run without installing them first. But your issue is that `main.py` is in the directory `packagetest/`, which means that `aux` exists in the "root" package since `aux.py` is in the same directory.

Comment: You can create a symlink and use your project folder as a library.  `ln -s packagetest -> /<path_to_folder>/packagetest`. Then access it without installing it. Make sure you create the symlink inside the python libraries folder.

Comment: [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner), so maybe I should forget about that? I just wanted a import that works in both cases

Comment: @LeonardoRick if an import is not relative to an installed package (with relative meaning that it starts with the name of such a package, like `packagetest.` in your case), it will usually not work reliably. It might break if you call it from a different directory, or if you move a file within the project. If you care about installing script elements (as implied by you calling one of your files `main.py`), you might be interested in reading up about [script_entrypoints](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point).

Comment: @LeonardoRick You have 3 ways to choose: `export PYTHONPATH`, `pip install .` and `pip install -e .` The latter is called "editable install" and is intended to "install in place" so you can continue editing the source code and it will be available for import.

Comment: Thanks for all you guys answering. I will dive into your links and maybe change my mind later. I was looking for something less editable, but maybe It's not something that I really need. For now I'll keep installing my packages before running them.